# How to get the vuejs filter to work on this products page?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm working on laravel online store application that uses vuejs on front-end, this is the entire code I'm using for front page, api calls work but doesn't update the products listed

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-white">
        <a-row type="flex" justify="center">
            <a-col :span="20">
                <a-row :gutter="[20, 30]" class="mt-20">
                    <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="12" :xl="12">
                        <a-carousel autoplay>
                            <div
                                v-for="item in frontSettings.bottom_banners_1_details"
                                :key="item.uid"
                            >
                                <img
                                    :src="item.url"
                                    :style="{ width: '100%' }"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </a-carousel>
                    </a-col>
                    <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="12" :xl="12">
                        <a-row :gutter="[20, 20]">
                            <a-col :span="24">
                                <a-carousel autoplay>
                                    <div
                                        v-for="item in frontSettings.bottom_banners_2_details"
                                        :key="item.uid"
                                    >
                                        <img
                                            :src="item.url"
                                            :style="{ width: '100%' }"
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </a-carousel>
                            </a-col>
                            <a-col :span="24">
                                <div
                                    v-for="item in frontSettings.bottom_banners_3_details"
                                    :key="item.uid"
                                >
                                    <img
                                        :src="item.url"
                                        :style="{ width: '100%' }"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </a-col>
                        </a-row>
                    </a-col>
                </a-row>

                <a-divider
                    v-if="
                        (frontSettings.bottom_banners_1_details &&
                            frontSettings.bottom_banners_1_details.length >
                                0) ||
                        (frontSettings.bottom_banners_2_details &&
                            frontSettings.bottom_banners_2_details.length >
                                0) ||
                        (frontSettings.bottom_banners_3_details &&
                            frontSettings.bottom_banners_3_details.length > 0)
                    "
                    dashed
                />

                <div
                    v-if="
                        frontSettings.featured_products_details &&
                        frontSettings.featured_products_details.length > 0
                    "
                >
                    <div style="text-align: center" class="mt-50 mb-40">
                        <a-typography-title
                            :level="3"
                            :style="{ marginBottom: '5px' }"
                        >
                            {{ frontSettings.featured_products_title }}
                        </a-typography-title>
                        <a-typography-title
                            v-if="frontSettings.featured_products_subtitle"
                            type="secondary"
                            :level="5"
                            :style="{ marginTop: '0px' }"
                        >
                            {{ frontSettings.featured_products_subtitle }}
                        </a-typography-title>
                    </div>

                    <div class="prdoct-card-list-body mt-20 mb-50">
                        <a-row :gutter="[30, 30]">
                            <a-col
                                v-for="product in featuredProducts"
                                :xs="24"
                                :sm="12"
                                :md="8"
                                :lg="6"
                                :xl="4"
                                :key="product.id"
                            >
                                <ProductCard
                                    :product="product"
                                    :key="product.id"
                                    :currency="currency"
                                />
                            </a-col>
                        </a-row>
                    </div>
                    <a-divider dashed />
                </div>

                <div
                    v-if="
                        frontSettings.featured_categories_details &&
                        frontSettings.featured_categories_details.length > 0
                    "
                >
                    <div style="text-align: center" class="mt-50 mb-40">
                        <a-typography-title
                            :level="3"
                            :style="{ marginBottom: '5px' }"
                        >
                            {{ frontSettings.featured_categories_title }}
                        </a-typography-title>
                        <a-typography-title
                            v-if="frontSettings.featured_categories_subtitle"
                            type="secondary"
                            :level="5"
                            :style="{ marginTop: '0px' }"
                        >
                            {{ frontSettings.featured_categories_subtitle }}
                        </a-typography-title>
                    </div>
                    <a-row
                        :gutter="[10, 10]"
                        class="mt-20 mb-50 featured-categories"
                    >
                        <a-col
                            :xs="24"
                            :sm="12"
                            :md="8"
                            :lg="4"
                            :xl="4"
                            v-for="featuredCategory in frontSettings.featured_categories_details"
                            :key="featuredCategory.id"
                        >
                            <div
                                style="
                                    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
                                    border-radius: 10px;
                                    border: 1px solid #eee;
                                "
                            >
                                <a-list
                                    item-layout="horizontal"
                                    :data-source="[featuredCategory]"
                                >
                                    <template #renderItem="{ item }">
                                        <a-list-item>
                                            <a-list-item-meta>
                                                <template #title>
                                                    {{ item.name }}
                                                </template>
                                                <template #avatar>
                                                    <a-avatar
                                                        :src="item.image_url"
                                                    />
                                                </template>
                                            </a-list-item-meta>
                                        </a-list-item>
                                    </template>
                                </a-list>
                            </div>
                        </a-col>
                    </a-row>
                    <a-divider dashed />
                </div>

                <div v-if="frontProductCards && frontProductCards.length > 0">
                    <div
                        v-for="frontProductCard in frontProductCards"
                        :key="frontProductCard.id"
                        class="prdoct-card-list"
                    >
                        <div style="text-align: center" class="mt-50 mb-40">
                            <a-typography-title
                                :level="3"
                                :style="{ marginBottom: '5px' }"
                            >
                                {{ frontProductCard.title }}
                            </a-typography-title>
                            <a-typography-title
                                v-if="frontProductCard.subtitle != ''"
                                type="secondary"
                                :level="5"
                                :style="{ marginTop: '0px' }"
                            >
                                {{ frontProductCard.subtitle }}
                            </a-typography-title>
                        </div>

                        <div class="prdoct-card-list-body mt-20 mb-50">
                            <a-row :gutter="[30, 30]">
                                <a-col
                                    v-for="product in frontProductCard.products_details"
                                    :xs="24"
                                    :sm="12"
                                    :md="8"
                                    :lg="6"
                                    :xl="4"
                                    :key="product.id"
                                >
                                    <ProductCard
                                        :product="product"
                                        :key="product.xid"
                                        :currency="currency"
                                    />
                                </a-col>
                            </a-row>
                        </div>
                        <a-divider dashed />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a-row class="mt-20 mb-20">
                    <a-col :span="24">
                        <a-carousel arrows>
                            <template #prevArrow>
                                <div
                                    class="custom-slick-arrow"
                                    style="left: 10px; zindex: 1"
                                >
                                    <left-circle-outlined />
                                </div>
                            </template>
                            <template #nextArrow>
                                <div
                                    class="custom-slick-arrow"
                                    style="right: 10px"
                                >
                                    <RightCircleOutlined />
                                </div>
                            </template>
                            <div
                                v-for="item in frontSettings.top_banners_details"
                                :key="item.uid"
                            >
                                <img
                                    :src="item.url"
                                    :style="{ width: '100%' }"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </a-carousel>
                    </a-col>
                </a-row>

            

                    <!-- Filters Section -->
                    <a-row :gutter="20" class="filter-row">
                        <!-- Brand Dropdown -->
                        <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="3" :xl="3">
                            <a-select
                                v-model="selectedBrand"
                                placeholder="Select Brand"
                                @change="fetchFilteredProducts"
                            >
                                <!-- Options for brands -->
                                <a-select-option
                                    v-for="brand in brands"
                                    :value="brand.id"
                                    :key="brand.id"
                                >
                                    {{ brand.name }}
                                </a-select-option>
                            </a-select>
                        </a-col>

                        <!-- Category Dropdown -->
                        <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="3" :xl="3">
                            <a-select
                                v-model="selectedCategory"
                                placeholder="Select Category"
                                @change="fetchFilteredProducts"
                            >
                                <!-- Options for categories -->
                                <a-select-option
                                    v-for="category in categories"
                                    :value="category.id"
                                    :key="category.id"
                                >
                                    {{ category.name }}
                                </a-select-option>
                            </a-select>
                        </a-col>

                        <!-- Sort Dropdown -->
                        <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="3" :xl="3">
                            <a-select
                                v-model="selectedSortOrder"
                                placeholder="Sort by"
                                @change="fetchFilteredProducts"
                            >
                                <a-select-option value="price_asc"
                                    >Price: Low to High</a-select-option
                                >
                                <a-select-option value="price_desc"
                                    >Price: High to Low</a-select-option
                                >
                            </a-select>
                        </a-col>

                        <!-- Search Field -->
                        <a-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :md="12" :lg="12" :xl="12">
                            <a-input-search
                                v-model="searchQuery"
                                placeholder="Search products"
                                @search="fetchFilteredProducts"
                            />
                        </a-col>
                    </a-row>
                    <div class="prdoct-card-list-body mt-20 mb-50">
                        <a-row :gutter="[20, 20]">
                            <a-col
                                v-for="product in allProducts"
                                :key="product.id"
                                :xs="12"
                                :sm="12"
                                :md="8"
                                :lg="6"
                                :xl="4"
                            >
                                <ProductCard
                                    :product="product"
                                    :currency="currency"
                                />
                            </a-col>
                        </a-row>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a-pagination
                            :current="paginationInfo.currentPage"
                            :total="paginationInfo.total"
                            :pageSize="paginationInfo.pageSize"
                            @change="handlePageChange"
                        ></a-pagination>
                    </div>

                    <a-divider dashed />
                </div>
            </a-col>
        </a-row>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, watch } from "vue";
import {
    RightOutlined,
    RightCircleOutlined,
    LeftCircleOutlined,
} from "@ant-design/icons-vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import ProductCard from "./components/ProductCard.vue";
import CategoryHeader from "./includes/CategoryHeader.vue";
import common from "../../../common/composable/common";
import { Pagination } from "ant-design-vue";

export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        RightOutlined,
        RightCircleOutlined,
        LeftCircleOutlined,
        ProductCard,
        CategoryHeader,
        Pagination,
    },
    setup() {
        const { frontWarehouse } = common();
        const route = useRoute();
        const frontSettings = ref({});
        const frontProductCards = ref([]);
        const featuredProducts = ref([]);
        const currency = ref({});

        const allProducts = ref([]);

        const brands = ref([]);

        const extractUniqueBrands = () => {
          
const brandSet = new Set();
    allProducts.value.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.brand && product.brand.slug) {
            const brandIdentifier = product.brand.slug + "-" + product.brand.name;
            if (!brandSet.has(brandIdentifier)) {
                brands.value.push({
                    id: product.brand.slug,
                    name: product.brand.name,
                });
                brandSet.add(brandIdentifier);
            }
        }
    });

        };

        const selectedBrand = ref(null); // Selected brand
        const selectedCategory = ref(null); // Selected category
        const searchQuery = ref(""); // Search query
        const selectedSortOrder = ref(null); // Selected sort order

        const fetchFilteredProducts = (page) => {
            let query = `front/all-products?page=${page}`;

            // Append search, sort, brand, and category parameters
            if (searchQuery.value) {
                query += `&search=${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery.value)}`;
            }
            if (selectedSortOrder.value) {
                query += `&sort=${selectedSortOrder.value}`;
            }
            if (selectedCategory.value) {
                query += `&category=${selectedCategory.value}`;
            }
            if (selectedBrand.value) {
                query += `&brand=${selectedBrand.value}`;
            }

            axiosFront
                .get(query)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(
                        "API response for page",
                        page,
                        ":",
                        response.data
                    );
                    allProducts.value = response.data.products.data;

                    extractUniqueBrands();

                    paginationInfo.value = {
                        ...paginationInfo.value,
                        total: response.data.products.total,
                        currentPage: response.data.products.current_page,
                        pageSize: response.data.products.per_page,
                    };
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error fetching filtered products:", error);
                });
        };

        const handlePageChange = (newPage) => {
            console.log("Page changed to:", newPage); // This should log the new page number
            fetchFilteredProducts(newPage);
        };

        const paginationInfo = ref({
            currentPage: 1,
            total: 0,
            pageSize: 30,
        });

        // Watch for changes in currentPage and fetch products accordingly
        watch(
            () => paginationInfo.value.currentPage,
            (newPage) => {
                fetchFilteredProducts(newPage);
            }
        );

        onMounted(() => {
            axiosFront
                .get(`front/homepage/${frontWarehouse.value.slug}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    currency.value = response.data.currency;
                    frontSettings.value = response.data.front_settings;
                    frontProductCards.value = response.data.front_product_cards;
                    featuredProducts.value =
                        frontSettings.value.featured_products_details;
                });

            fetchFilteredProducts(paginationInfo.value.currentPage);
        });

        return {
            frontSettings,
            frontProductCards,
            featuredProducts,
            currency,
            allProducts,
            brands,
            fetchFilteredProducts,
            paginationInfo,
            handlePageChange,
        };
    },
});
</script>

...
```

**And This here is the controllers function code calling handling the data**

```
public function allProducts(Request $request)
    {
        // Extract query parameters
        $brandId = $request->input('brand');
        $categoryId = $request->input('category');
        $searchQuery = $request->input('search');
        $sortOrder = $request->input('sort');

        // Basic query with relationships
        $query = Product::with(['details', 'details.tax', 'brand', 'category'])
            ->whereHas('details', function ($query) {
                $query->where('current_stock', '>', 0);
            });

        // Filter by brand slug if provided
        if ($request->has('brand')) {
            $brandSlug = $request->input('brand');
            $query->whereHas('brand', function ($query) use ($brandSlug) {
                $query->where('slug', $brandSlug);
            });
        }

        // Apply other filters like category, search, etc. similarly
        if ($request->has('category')) {
            $categoryId = $request->input('category');
            $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categoryId) {
                $query->where('id', $categoryId);
            });
        }

        if ($request->has('search')) {
            $searchQuery = $request->input('search');
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($searchQuery) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $searchQuery . '%')
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $searchQuery . '%');
                // Add more fields as needed
            });
        }

        if ($request->has('sort')) {
            switch ($request->input('sort')) {
                case 'price_asc':
                    $query->orderBy('sales_price', 'asc');
                    break;
                case 'price_desc':
                    $query->orderBy('sales_price', 'desc');
                    break;
                    // Add more sorting options as needed
            }
        }

        // Pagination and response
        $products = $query->paginate(30);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $product->makeHidden('purchase_price');
        }

        return ApiResponse::make('Data Fetched', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors logged, just all products get displayed and pagination also not working properly, pagination pulling the correct data per page btw.

any help spotting the problem is much appreciated.

I've tried various approaches and ideas from chatGPT but no luck when I run the application

Comment: where is the code where you tried implementing the filters in VueJs?

Comment: above the product card there's a row with brand, category and sort dropdown. and a search input

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you use `page` parameter any where in your controller. You just hard code `$query->paginate(30)` without changing the page.

As I imagine, you fetched your data, then you re-paginate it each time you sending request. So controller will always send `currentPage = 1`. You must have a problem when click page 2, then it's immediately change to page 1.

I believe `$query->paginate()` method only suitable if you trying to use Laravel's view (Blade). That method will return a special object with special link for you to call. When you call them, you can get the content of new page.

For RESTFUL, you should use Eloquent `offset` and `limit` to implement an actual pagination